# Calculating the characteristic polynomials of two similar matrices yields different results. Where's the error?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, characteristic-polynomial, similar-matrices

I have been struggling with a problem concerning matrices and their characteristic polynomials. It is known that *similar matrices have the same characteristic polynomial*, but my calculations aren't showing that.

Suppose we have the following matrix:

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}
-5 & 2\\
4 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$$

Multiplying the first row by $4/5$ and adding it to the second row, we get the similar matrix

$$B=\begin{pmatrix}
-5 & 2\\
0 & \frac{13}{5}
\end{pmatrix}$$

However, $\det(A-xI)=x^2+4x-13$, while $\det(B-xI)=x^2+\frac{12}{5}x-13\neq \det(A-xI)$.

Another example with matrix $A$: Multiplying the second column by $-4$ and adding it to the first column, we obtain the similar matrix

$$C=\begin{pmatrix}
-13 & 2\\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$$

Notice that $\det(C-xI)=x^2+12x-13\neq \det(A-xI)$.

I have checked my calculations many times trying to spot an error, and have tried to figure out the wrong usage of some theorem, but I don't know what is going on.

Comment: check the definition of [similar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_similarity) matrices

Comment: Please try to make your titles informative. “Can you spot what is wrong” doesn’t tell any potential readers what the question is actually about.

Comment: $A$ and $B$ are not similar.

Comment: Elementary row operations do not preserve similarity.

Comment: Elementary row operations preserve the set of solutions to $Ax=0$ (and are extremely helpful in that context). But they don't preserve everything (for example, not the column space).

Comment: nor do elementary column operations

Comment: Now I see the mistake is that elementary row (or column) operations do not necessarily yield a similar matrix to the original one. Thank you all.

Comment: I don't get the downvotes.  OP did due diligence in showing his efforts and (mis)understanding.  He knew something was wrong.

Answer (score 3):

**Lesson learned:**

a matrix obtained by elementary row (or column) operations

is not necessarily [similar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_similarity)
to the original matrix.